# Kendo Grid pass array parameter

Tags: arrays, parameters, grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo Grid like this (read dataSource)

```
 .Read(read => read.Action("ReadUserStore", "User").Data("DataforUserStore"))
```

This Grid is inside the partialView, and this partialView is the Tabcontent in a kendotabStrip.

Now, i want to pass parameter like this :

```
 function DataforUserStore(){

    var arrID = new Array();
    arrID.push(1);
    arrID.push(2);
    return {
        BranchList :arrID,
        UserIDSys : 1
    }
}
```

And Controller is :

```
 public ActionResult ReadUserStore([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int[] BranchList, int UserIDSys)
```

But it's not work, the UserIDSys is passed to action but BranchList can't.. Why...??

Can you help me ?? Thanks for advance. !

Answer (score 1):

I've had something similar to this, try changing your return to:

```
return JSON.stringify({
    BranchList :arrID,
    UserIDSys : 1
});
```